# How to save chorme tts output to client or server (browser only)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm really excited to learn that Google Chrome now support inbuilt TTS engine that can speak text using both chrome extensions.

How can I save this file on the server or client side?

Update: I need a way to do this on for a chrome extension or web apps only. thanks.

Comment: for ubuntu : https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder

Comment: thanks! i'll check if chrome.tts works on ubuntu.. also after a lot of searching, also found this: http://www.totalrecorder.com/ (for windows).. it also has a command line option

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save the audio generated via Google TTS into a file today. Here's how I did it:

1. Download "[TTS Speech Synthesizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.annabozzi.speech.synthesizer)" and "[Google Text-to-speech](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts)" on an Android device
2. In Android Settings -> Language and input -> Text-to-speech output, select "Google Text-to-speech", adjust other settings (language, speech rate, etc.) here according to your needs.
3. Open "TTS Speech Synthesizer", input the text you want to convert to speech, click "Click to synthesize", open app menu, click "Save to MP3"
4. Find the audio file in `/storage/sdcard0`, using any file explorer (e.g. [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop))